# How to shift the center of video in HTML?

Tags: html, css, video

I managed to crop top of the video with a position property. After that, I want to adjust the center of the video.

How can I achieve this?

Sorry for lacking for an explanation, I meant something like set a `position` in `background` property to be at the center. I want to do it with video instead of a picture.

This is my code :

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -101;
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}

#video-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: -500px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div id='video' class="container">
    <video id='video-background' preload muted autoplay loop>
      <source src='../../assets/video/keyboard_02.mp4'  height = '100' type='video/mp4'/>
      <source src='../../assets/video/keyboard_02.webm' height = '100' type='video/webm'/>
      <source src='../../assets/video/keyboard_02.ogv'  height = '100'  type='video/ogg'/>
    </video>
    <h1 class="display-3">Live like A Lazy Nerd.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is not clear. Centered where ? and how ? centered on the page ? verticaly or orizontaly ? add some details, or an image to explain what is the result you are looking for.

Comment: why the negative z-indexes?  seems really odd to need those?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your requirements.

If you are talking about placing the video in the center of the `.jumbotron` you can simply target the `#video` container and add `text-align: center;` like this:

```
#video{
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding:0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Below is a simplified version of your CSS.

```css
.jumbotron {
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);  
}

#video{
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding:0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div id='video' class="container">
    <video id='video-background' preload muted autoplay loop>
      <source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4' height='100' type='video/mp4'/>
      <source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm' height='100' type='video/webm'/>
      <source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv' height='100' type='video/ogg'/>
    </video>
    <h1 class="display-3">Live like A Lazy Nerd.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```